# Почему не работает file_put_contents?

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какой причине может не работать `file_put_contents`? Что в этом коде не так?

```
if(isset($_POST['save']) )
    {
        $file=file("us/db/fav/$us_id");
        $fav=$_GET[review];
        file_put_contents($file, $fav, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=0; url=page.php'>";
        exit();
    }

<form action='' name='' method='post'>
<button name='save' type='submit' value=''>Записать</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Что конкретно не работает? Вы уверены что именно ``file_put_contents``. Может проблема в ``$_GET['review']``?

Comment: Ошибка явно выше....и если бы включили отображение ошибок - вы её даже увидели бы.

Comment: Возможно, file("/us/db/fav/$us_id"); url должна идти от корня сайта?

Comment: @АлександрМаринов путь /us/db/fav/$us_id - это НЕ от корня сайта. и никакие url здесь не при чем. В файловой системе на диске нет никаких url